# Lambdas in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

How to use lambda expressions in C++/CLI?

Comment: A c++ whicn are used in visual studio (in that i can use .net libraries) i port system linq and now i want to use some function which use  lamda expressions on c# like WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, lambdas are really just syntactic sugar for creating delegates. C++/CLI [supports delegates](http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/classes/Lesson15c.htm), so you can still do all of the same stuff in C++/CLI that you can do in C#, you just don't get to use the nifty syntax.

Comment: i agree with you but i already have programm writting on  C++/CLI

Answer (score 1):

I've found this response from a [Microsoft employee on the vc blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx#9034197) to a question regarding C++ 0x lambda and managed code interoperability:

> You can only pass a variable with a
>   managed type as an argument to a
>   lambda - you can't capture a variable
>   that has a managed type.
>        We have no plans to "merge" lambdas and delegates.

Answer (score 0):

According to [What's New in Visual C++ 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465215(VS.100).aspx) you can use lambda expressions only in VS2010.

Comment: what if i have vs-2008? how can i use WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post ?

Comment: I don't think he's asking about C++0x lambdas, he's asking about using .NET lambdas from C++/CLI

Comment: Do you mean writing them? I don't think you can write delegates in lambda style in C++/CLI.

Comment: you right what was being done in the. NET by lambda functions in C + + / CLI is a pointer to a function